# Assigning value to a column based on periods derived from other columns using vector approach in R

Tags: r

I have a df like this:

```
x <- data.frame("date1" = c("2018-09-12","2018-09-18", "2019-06-23"), "date2" = c("2018-09-10","2018-09-13","2018-12-12"))
> x
       date1      date2
1 2018-09-12 2018-09-10
2 2018-09-18 2018-09-13
3 2019-06-23 2018-12-12
```

Now I would do an `unique` on date1 which will result in unique date value. I would then create a new column and assign value of period to it based on date in col date2, like this

```
     date1      date2     period
1 2018-09-12 2018-09-10   0
2 2018-09-18 2018-09-13   1 (as period 1: is 2018-09-12 to 2018-09-18 and date2 lies in it)
3 2019-06-23 2018-12-12   2  (as period 2: is 2018-09-18 to 2019-06-23 and date2 lies in that)
```

Is there is a way to do it in a vector form in R.
Thanks

Comment: Is the expected correct?  `c(0, unlist(Map(function(u, v) sum(x$date2 >= u & x$date2 <= v), x$date1[-nrow(x)], x$date1[-1])))`

Comment: @akrun I gave the expected just to give an idea. Basically I would have to do an 'unique' on that column to derive time periods and then assign those time periods based on date2 value to each row.

Comment: @akrun your output is correct except the last value which should be 2. The second period starts from 2018-09-18 to 2019-06-23 and 2018-12-12 lies in this period so should get a value 2. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
periods = as.Date(sort(unique(x$date1)))
x$period = apply(as.data.frame(x$date2), 1, function(x){
                findInterval(as.Date(x), periods)
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dates in `date1` to find intervals in `date2`

```
findInterval(x$date2, x$date1)
#[1] 0 1 2
```